# AS3: DescibeType not working with interfaces

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I need to get a methode list of interface, I am trying to achieve this with [describeType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29), but it's not working. Any idea why?

```
var xml:XML = MyInterface; // Getting empty xml object.

public interface MyInterface{
    function methode1();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the interface:

```
public interface TheInterface 
{
    function method1():void;
    function method2():void;
}
```

The code :

```
var xml:XML = describeType(TheInterface);

var xmlList:XMLList = xml.child("factory").child("method");

for each(var key:XML in xmlList) {
    var method:String = key.attribute("name");
    trace(method);
}
```

Produces the output :

```
method2
method1
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah it works. In debugger I saw that the xml is empty but not null, so I misunderstood it, tnx.